# convert Moodle php single_button to a link

Tags: php, button, moodle

I need to change the following code to replace the button with a clickable link
something like
Course >

Basically I would still use the resulting link but instead of a button, I need it to be a link button. So that user can middle click and open it in a different tab if needed.

```
if (has_capability('block/progress:overview', $this->context)) {
     $parameters = array('progressbarid' => $this->instance->id, 'courseid' => $COURSE->id);
     $url = new moodle_url('/blocks/progress/overview.php', $parameters);
     $label = get_string('overview', 'block_progress');
     $options = array('class' => 'overviewButton');
     $this->content->text .= $OUTPUT->single_button($url, $label, 'post', $options);
}
```

Its the **single_button** element that I need to change.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
$this->content->text .= $OUTPUT->single_button($url, $label, 'post', $options);
```

With this

```
$this->content->text .= html_writer::link($url, $label);
```

Comment: Hi Russell, That does it. But Can I add a button class like ` <a href="link" class="btn btn-secondary">Open Link</a> `

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Russel. I just added the class like this:

```
$this->content->text .= html_writer::link($url, $label,array('class' => 'btn btn-secondary'));
```

Thanks for your help.